# Как смотреть содержимое сетевых пакетов в линукс?

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, пакет, сетевое-администрирование

Я хочу узнать структуру пакета beacon frame, который постоянно высылается моим роутером.
Какие есть утилиты для чтения пакетов в kali linux? Какие вообще есть программы для чтения пакетов и вывода информации из них?

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark, tshark, tcpdump + любой редактор кода